# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Student' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I got this error when I insert values into the database. I already set to ON of Identity specification property in SQL Sever Management Studio but still I face this error. I tried 
this way also `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student ON`, add this line in my SQL command but it's not run.

`Default.aspx.cs`:

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=INAFFFP1IT004W\MYSQL;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=sa;Password=test@1234;");
    con.Open();

    string SId = tbid.Text;
    string FirstName = tbfirstname.Text;
    string LastName = tblastname.Text;
    string StartDate = tbstart.Text;
    string EndDate = tbend.Text;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
     cmd.CommandText = "insert into Student(SId,FirstName,LastName,StartDate,EndDate) values('" + SId + "','" + FirstName + "','" + LastName + "','" + StartDate + "','" + EndDate + "')";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SId", tbid.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", tbfirstname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", tblastname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", tbstart.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", tbend.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
    tbid.Text = "";
    tbfirstname.Text = "";
    tblastname.Text = "";
    tbstart.Text = "";
    tbend.Text = "";
    tbid.Focus();
}

 **Default.aspx**:

 <head runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode: 2,
        target: "tbstart",
        dateFormat: "%M/%d/%Y"
    });
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode: 2,
        target: "tbend",
        dateFormat: "%M/%d/%Y"
    });
 };
</script>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 64px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="SId"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text="FirstName"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbfirstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbllastname" runat="server" Text="LastName"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tblastname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblstart" runat="server" Text="StartDate"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbstart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblend" runat="server" Text="EndDate"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbend" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnupdate" runat="server" onclick="btnupdate_Click" 
                Text="Update" Width="63px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                onclick="btnsubmit_Click1" Width="102px" />
        </td>
        <td class="style1">
     <asp:Button ID="btnsearch" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: A bit off topic, you have a `using` statement for your `SqlCommand` I would use one for your `SqlConnection` too so it disposes and closes the connection when you are done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to execute this command text.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student ON;" + 
                   "insert into Student(SId,FirstName,LastName,StartDate,EndDate) " + 
                    "values(@id, @firstname, @lastname, @startdate, @enddate);" + 
                    "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student OFF;" ;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", SId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", FirstName);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", LastName);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", StartDate);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", endDate);
```

Note also the a parameter should be inserted in your command text using its prefix '@' and not concatenating strings.

Comment: Thanks Steve.These solution helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. Your solution was helpful for me. :)

Answer (score 5):

The SQL command

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON
```

has a session scope. You need to include this in the query that you sent to the database in your C# code.

Be aware that you can only have a single table with identity_insert on. MSDN:

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT
>   property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON,
>   and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table,
>   Microsoft® SQL Server™ returns an error message that states SET
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code either on your program or in the SQL Server Management studio.For more information check [msdn website here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

> SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student ON
>
> GO
>
> INSERT INTO Student ON (ID, Name) VALUES (31, 'sss')